# Rails - selecting parent based on a criteria on its last updated has_many child

Tags: ruby-on-rails

hi I have two rails model

```
class Feedback < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :conversations, :dependent => :destroy

class Conversation < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :feedback, :touch => true
```

in the schema

```
create_table "conversations", :force => true do |t|
t.text     "content"
t.integer  "feedback_id"
t.datetime "created_at"
t.datetime "updated_at"
t.string   "author"
end

create_table "feedbacks", :force => true do |t|
t.datetime "created_at"
t.datetime "updated_at"
t.string   "status"
end
```

note that i have taken out columns and relationships from the models that do not matter for this question so please kindly don't suggest I restructure the models differently

In my controller i have a method where I want to select feedbacks with status "unread" and whose last updated conversation's author is "admin"

i know that the following selects feedbacks with status "unread", but how do i expand on it to select those which meets my conversation author requirement?

```
@feedbacks = Feedback.where(:status => "unread")
```

---

I found this website (http://m.onkey.org/find-users-with-at-least-n-items) which seems to be doing something remotely similar in that it selects parent based on conditions related to child model, but still trying to figure out how to modify it for my case...

thanks much in advance!!!

Comment: I added in an answer below... but as a quick tip, if you are wanting to test out things that involve data... use the Rails Console. It is a lifesaver and involves far less headaches when just needing to test methods really quickly than having to reload your browser everytime

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It should work:

```
@feedbacks = Feedback.includes(:conversations).where("status = ? and conversations.author = ?", unread_state, admin_id).select{|a| a.conversations.last().author == admin}
```

Of course include your current values to the `unread_status`, `admin` and `admin_id` part.

Comment: this seems to work!!! can you explain to me why it seems to look at only the last updated conversation's author even though the query doesn't mention anything about order("updated_at DESC") or the likes? I did tested by changing one feedback's second last conversation's author to "admin" and your answer successfully not selected that feedback

Comment: actually i take it back. it had the problem which i was asking. I realized the feedback that i manually changed did not have status = "unread", but after i fixed that and reran your answer, that feedback was returned as the result as well....

Comment: no, as mentioned, i only want to select feedbacks whose last updated conversations is of author = admin

Comment: slight modification below works for me finally. Thanks for your help!!!

`@feedbacks = Feedback.includes(:conversations).where("status = ?", "unread").select{|a| a.conversations.last().author == "admin"}`

Answer (score 0):

```
@feedbacks = Feedback.where("status = ? and author = ?", "unread", "admin")
```

Comment: thanks but doesn't work (yes I tried). please note that feedbacks can have more than one conversations, i only want to consider the last updated conversation which also has author = "admin"

Comment: the error is as below:

Mysql2::Error: Unknown column 'author' in 'where clause': SELECT `feedbacks`.* FROM `feedbacks`  WHERE (status = 'unread' and author = 'admin')

Comment: The `author` I used was assuming your column was named `author`.. replace that with the real column name

Comment: the column is indeed named author, but it's in the conversations model, not the feedback model. I have listed the columns name in the schema in my first post. thanks

Comment: You could do this... `@feedbacks = Feedback.where(:status => 'unread').conversations.where(:author => 'admin').last`

Comment: thanks for the updated answer. still not working, error : "undefined method `conversations' for #<ActiveRecord::Relation:0x007fde1bb4aef0>". i SWEAR my model is called  conversations (per the schema i copied). i also tried variation of Conversations, conversation, Conversation